# MongoDB generates duplicates in .aggregate()

Tags: mongodb

The structure of my database is something like this.

```
    {
      _id : ObjectId(...),
      no : 2,
      dates : [
        { year : 2016, month : 3, grade : {} },
        { year : 2016, month : 2, grade : {} },
        { year : 2016, month : 1, grade : {} },
      ]
    },
    {
      _id : ObjectId(...),
      no : 1,
      dates : [
        { year : 2016, month : 3, grade : {} },
        { year : 2016, month : 2, grade : {} },
        { year : 2016, month : 1, grade : {} },
      ]
    }
```

Now, I need to find a document and sort them by year, then by month. I have the following code below:

```
    db.something.aggregate([
      { '$match' : { 'no' : 2 }},
      { '$unwind' : '$dates'},
      { '$sort' : {
        'dates.year' : 1,
        'dates.month' : 1
      }},
      { '$group' : {
        '_id' : '$no',
        'dates' : { '$push' : '$dates' }
      }}
    ]).pretty();
```

I think I'm approaching it right but it somehow generates duplicates. Something like this:

```
    {
      _id : ObjectId(...),
      no : 2,
      dates : [
        { year : 2016, month : 1, grade : {} },
        { year : 2016, month : 1, grade : {} },
        { year : 2016, month : 2, grade : {} },
        { year : 2016, month : 2, grade : {} },
        { year : 2016, month : 3, grade : {} },
        { year : 2016, month : 3, grade : {} },
      ]
    }
```

If I remove `$sort` and `$group` the result contains no duplicates. I am pretty sure I inserted everything right and it does not have duplicates or whatsoever in my database. What do you think is wrong with it? I am completely blank as to how I should proceed.

Many thanks!

**[EDIT]**

Okay, I just reinstalled MongoDB and it just magically works. I still don't know what happened though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it  looks like your structure could contains similar entries (per objectId), and after `$unwind` then `$group` they are becoming visible.

To avoid that change :

```
'dates' : { '$push' : '$dates' }
```

To:

```
'dates' : { '$adToSet' : '$dates' }
```

as this will only add unique values to an array